# Prove that $p(x)=(x-a)q(x)$ for some $q(x)\in R[x]$ of degree= (degree of $p)-1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with identity. Let $a\in R$ is a root of $p(x)\in R[x]$ . Prove that $p(x)=(x-a)q(x)$ for some $q(x)\in R[x]$ of degree= (degree of $p)-1$.

If $R$ were a Euclidean domain then it is obvious. But $R$ is not necessarily a ED. So what I was trying to do is showing $p(x)\in (x-a)$; the ideal generated by $x-a$.

I tried defining a homomorphism $f:R[x]\rightarrow R$ by $f(x)=a$ and tried to show ker$f=(x-a)$. But when I was going to show it, I felt like showing the same thing that asks in the question. So no success. Can anybody please give me at least a hint? I feel like this is a standard question. So I searched through MSE for similar questions but could not find. If you find a duplicate please copy a link and then I will delete this question.

Comment: Division by the monic polynomial $x-a$ should work well in this more general context.

Comment: Yes, and it leads to funny factorizations. For instance in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, $2$ is a root of $3x$, but $3x = 3(x-2)$...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents us from doing the usual polynomial division by hand. In this way we arrive at
$$
 p(x) = (x-a)q(x) + r
$$
where $r \in R$ is some constant.

More formally: Notice that for every polynomial $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n b_k x^k$ of degree $n \geq 1$ we have
$$
 p(x)
 = \sum_{k=0}^n b_k x^k
 = (x-a) b_n x^{n-1}
   + \left( a b_n x^{n-1} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b_k x^k \right),
$$
where the second polynomial of the right hand side is of degree at most $n-1$. Because for every constant polynomial $c$ we have $p(x) = 0 \cdot (x-a) + c$ we can use induction to get our desired decomposition $p(x) = (x-a)q(x) + r$,

If $p(a) = 0$ then evaluating at $a$ gives $0 = p(a) = r, $so $p(x) = (x-a)q(x)$.